# PyHive - Long running query timeout - [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

I am running `Hive queries` from `Python` using `PyHive`. One of the query is taking around 12-15 minutes to complete. I could see it completed on `Hadoop` `ResourceManager UI`, however I am seeing bellow timeout error on `Python`.

> Error:Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/home/mrjadav/python/thunderbolt.py", line 704, in main() File
>   "/home/mrjadav/python/thunderbolt.py", line 662, in main
>   getColoLatency() File "/home/mrjadav/python/thunderbolt.py", line 582,
>   in getColoLatency dataSet =
>   saveHqlResultToXls(queryString=queryString, caption='Colo Latency
>   Breakdown', configuration=g_hive_config_heavy) File
>   "/home/mrjadav/python/thunderbolt.py", line 636, in saveHqlResultToXls
>   dataSet=cursor.fetchall() File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/common.py", line 136, in
>   fetchall return list(iter(self.fetchone, None)) File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/common.py", line 105, in
>   fetchone self._fetch_while(lambda: not self._data and self._state !=
>   self._STATE_FINISHED) File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/common.py", line 45, in
>   _fetch_while self._fetch_more() File "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 386, in
>   _fetch_more response = self._connection.client.FetchResults(req) File "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line
>   714, in FetchResults return self.recv_FetchResults() File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line
>   726, in recv_FetchResults (fname, mtype, rseqid) =
>   iprot.readMessageBegin() File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py",
>   line 134, in readMessageBegin sz = self.readI32() File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py",
>   line 217, in readI32 buff = self.trans.readAll(4) File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py",
>   line 60, in readAll chunk = self.read(sz - have) File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line
>   166, in read self._read_frame() File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/**init**.py", line
>   170, in _read_frame header = self._trans.readAll(4) File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py",
>   line 60, in readAll chunk = self.read(sz - have) File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py",
>   line 117, in read buff = self.handle.recv(sz) error: [Errno 110]
>   Connection timed out